# Swift Remove element from an array and then remove the same element from an array inside of a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift2, xcode7

So I have a struct and a dictionary that look like this:

```
struct minStruct {

var labelText:String?
var descText:String?
var imaginator:UIImage?
var rea:String?

var url:NSURL?}

var dict = [String:[minStruct]]()
```

Thus, I have a dictionary with the value as an array of structs. In my application I create an array of all the structs inside the dictionary to be able to show the structs in a tableView, which is done by this code:

```
let dictValues = Array(dict.values)
let dictFlat = Array(dictValues.flatten())
```

The new array dictFlat is used for populating the tableView, as it contains every struct that was contained inside of the original dictionary. If I would like to remove a struct from the tableView, i would of course remove it from the array dictFlat, however I need to remove the same struct from the original dictionary (dict) to achieve what I want. So my question is simply how to remove the same struct that is deleted from the array dictFlat from the dictionary dict. To clarify, you could you this example:

```
dict = ["Food":[minStruct(labelText: "this is a string", descText: "Also a string", imaginator: UIImage(named: "image-name")!, rea: "also a string", url: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")]]
```

Now dictFlat will contain the struct displayed inside of dict above, and now I want to delete that struct from both. Using swipe to delete from the tableView, the only struct that will be deleted is the one inside of dictFlat (using the indexPath to delete just as you would usually do when deleting from a tableView). Now I want to delete the same item which was deleted from dictFlat and also from the tableView, from the original dictionary (dict). So what I want is to check if dict contains the struct that was deleted from dictFlat, and if it does contain it, it shall be deleted.

I hope that I was clear enough, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What is the trouble? See the example, I used there [Int] as a value, but it could be anything else

```
var dict:[String:[Int]] = [:]

let arr0 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let arr1 = [2,3,4,5,6]

dict["arr0"] = arr0
dict["arr1"] = arr1

// working copy
var arr = dict["arr0"] ?? []

// remove one value
arr.removeAtIndex(2)

// update your dictionary
dict["arr0"] = arr

print(dict) // ["arr1": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "arr0": [1, 2, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Almost what I needed, I think was wasn't clear enough. I want to get the struct (or in your case the int) that is being deleted from the array (the one you called arr). After I get that specifik struct, I want to check if it exists inside of dict, and if it does, I want to delete it. I would like to add that I am new to swift so I'm not really familiar with the methods, but I want a method that checks if the dictionary contains a certain struct and as I said, if it does contain it, I want it to be deleted. Sorry for my unclear way of explaining things.

Comment: Also, I don't want the array that the struct is being deleted from to be an array of only one value from the dictionary (not only one of the arrays of structs). Look at my question where I created the array dictFlat and you'll probably understand what I mean.

Comment: markus don't do any unnecessary work! you table source is an arr. if you modify the arr, update your dict. that is all you need. you don't need to check nothing at all ....

Comment: I know what you mean, but the array arr is only one of the dictionarys arrays (in your case you have arr0 and arr1). Doesn't arr only consist of arr0? I want to have both arr0 and arr1 in one array, and therefore use that array to populate the tableView. I must be missing something here, and I am sorry for being so difficult :(

Comment: if you change arr0, you have to update dict["arr0"], if you change arr1, you have to update dict["arr1"]

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thanks for taking your time :)